# How to access a method a Spring Bean from a class not in the Spring Container

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm not a [Spring](https://spring.io/) pro, so please bear with me....

I have three classes:

```
class SpringBeanA {
    public aMethod() {
        .....
    }
}

class SpringBeanB {

    @Autowired SpringBeanA a;

    public bMethod() {
        a.method();
    }
}

class NONSpringClass {
    .....
    b.method();
    .....
}
```

`b.method()` gives a null pointer error, both when accesed via the instances `SpringBeanB b = new SpringBeanB()` and autowiring SpringBeanB to NONSpringClass.

The autowiring:

```
class NONSpringClass {

    @Autowired SpringBeanB b;

    .....
    b.method();
    .....
}
```

How can I successfully call `b.method()`?

Comment: Show us how you do _autowiring SpringBeanB to NONSpringClass_.

Comment: I just updated my question with how I've been autowiring @ Sotirios Delimanolis. Thanks for the response.

Comment: And let us see how you are using `NONSpringClass`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Spring initializes all the objects and keep it in Spring Application Context. You have couple different ways to get access to objects inside Application context

First create a spring configuration class to inject ApplicationContext in to a private attribute and expose as static method.

```
@Configuration
class StaticApplicationContext implements ApplicationContextAware{

  static ApplicationContext applicationContext = null;

  public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context)    throws BeansException {
    applicationContext = context;
  }
  /**
   * Note that this is a static method which expose ApplicationContext
   **/
  public static ApplicationContext getContext(){
        return applicationContext;
  }

}
```

Now you can try this in your non spring class,

```
((SpringBeanB)StaticApplicationContext.getContext.getBean("b")).bMethod();
```

Please keep in mind, invoking getContext method before spring context initialization may cause NullPointerException. Also accessing beans outside of spring container is not a recommended approach. Ideal way will be to move all beans in to spring container to manage.

If you want to access SpringApplicationContext from a java Servelet please refer [WebApplicationContextUtils](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/WebApplicationContextUtils.html)

Comment: This wont work unless `NONSpringClass` becomes a Spring bean.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza See StaticApplicationContext is a spring bean (@Configuration) and exposed getContext as static. I mentioned risk of NPE in an caution

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do this is using ApplicationContext.getBean().

It's worth pointing out that this is considered bad practice, since it breaks inversion of control.

Comment: You cannot inject `ApplicationContext` in a non-spring bean.

Comment: ApplicationContext is an interface, not a class

Comment: I realize it's an interface. I should have been more clear by stating that some class implementing the ApplicationContext interface should be used. @Luiggi Mendoza, see kamoor's answer above for how to access an ApplicationContext  from a non-spring bean.

Answer (score -1):

Either you make Spring manage your `NONSpringClass` and enable injection of `SpringBeanB` in `NONSpringClass` class or you have to manually inject a proper instance of `SpringBeanB` in your `NONSpringClass` reference. In the latter approach, Spring has nothing to do, and you manually have to create the necessary instances and inject them using setters.

Comment: I think he's looking for the actual mechanics of accessing the bean.

Comment: @DavisYoshida this is not possible unless Spring is used, which falls in the former solution proposal. But probably OP don't/can't do it.

Comment: Usually, constructor injection is used for mandatory dependencies, and setters are for optional dependencies.

Comment: You can definitely take out ApplicationContext and expose as static method. It is not a preferred way but will work